# How to fill a jsp form by the data from MySQL database?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I have a jsp page in which there is a dropdown list of some products which is populated from the database. What I want is, when the user selects a product, I want the rate field to be populated automatically from the database. 
My jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<title>Purchase new product </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[name=date]').datepicker();
     });

     function multiply()
     {
        var q = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
        var r = document.getElementById('rateid').value;
        document.getElementById('total').value = q*r;
     }
</script>
<div class="container">
<h1>Place your order:</h1><br/>
    <form method="post" action="PurchaseController" name="pform"> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Product:</td>
        <td><select name="selectedProduct">
                <option value=0>Select one</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${product}" var="product">
                        <option value="${product.pid}"><c:out value="${product.name}" /> </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity:</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" oninput="multiply()" 
             onkeypress="return event.charCode >=48" min="1" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rate:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rateid" oninput="multiply()" <%--  value="<c:out value="${product.rate}" />" --%> >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total" readonly ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" required></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger">
    </form> 
    <br/>
    <a href="index.jsp">Back to home</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I uncomment the commented parts in the "Rate" field in the above code, I get the NumberFormatException error as follows:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/purchase.jsp] at line [55]

52:         <tr>
53:             <td>Rate:</td>
54:             <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rateid" oninput="multiply()" 
55:              value="<c:out value="${product.rate}" />" >
56:             </td>
57:         </tr>
58:             <td>Total:</td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.product.controller.ProductController.doGet(ProductController.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "rate"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:150)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
    org.apache.jsp.purchase_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f1(purchase_jsp.java:310)
    org.apache.jsp.purchase_jsp._jspService(purchase_jsp.java:178)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.product.controller.ProductController.doGet(ProductController.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I tried changing the type of input field of Rate to "number" but the same error occurs.

As the error is shown in the `value="<c:out value="${product.rate}" />"` line and there is no error when I comment this, I presume that I am using the EL in wrong ways?

But the list of products in the drop down is showing properly where I have used EL as well.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The product class is as follows:

```
public class Product {
    private int pid;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private int rate;
    private int total;
    private Date date;

    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }
    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me everything looks good; are you sure you didnt inserted 'rate' as a value?

Try outputting rate without el and see what the actual value is:

```
${product.rate}
```

Create a javascript function

```
function setRate(el) {
      document.getElementById("rate").value = el.value;
}
```

And add this to the select:

```
<select name="selectedProduct" onchange=setRate(this)>
```

Comment: Tried using "${product.rate}" with and without quotes but the same error occurs. "are you sure you didnt inserted 'rate' as a value?" - Could you clarify what you mean? The value of rate exists in the database.

Comment: Change <c:out value="${product.rate}" /> to ${product.rate} for now just to examine the value...it is as somehow the value itself is "rate" (instead of a value that was input by the user).

As you can see in the stacktrace:
For input string: "rate" meaning that the value of property rate is 'rate'.

Comment: Changed as per your suggestion but the same error appears. The rate field has numerical values which I can see in the workbench!

Comment: Please add the product bean to your question. Its too strange. Outputting ${product.rate} shouldn do any parsing. The c:out should be called for the rate..may be the stack is different? _jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f1 should be called.

Comment: First of all try changing <c:forEach items="${product}" var="product"> into another var name like var="_product" or something..

Comment: Tried that but that does not help either!

Comment: email me the files at rey333@gmail.com

Comment: I've sent you the email. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Ok, found it: your ${product.rate} is outside the <c:forEach loop. So it doesn't matter which property you access (I tried product.name) the error will always occur.

Comment: If you try ${product} you will see the last product from the loop (you need to override the toString() to see its property values) but accessing any property will fail.

Comment: Why do want the rate of the text input to be the same as the rate of the LAST product in the loop? That LOGIC is WRONG and STUPID. If you want a default rate, then add a new object to the model and use that in the jsp. For example setAttribute("defaultRate", new Long(300));

Comment: Product is a List collection. Stop using it outside the loop in the jsp.

Comment: What I want is when the user selects a product, I want its rate to be displayed in the rate textbox from the database. Then the user types the quantity he requires and the product of rate and quantity is displayed in the total textbox. How do I achieve this?

Comment: For the user to selects a product you can use javascript to fill it in the rate column. Add the onchange attribute to the select input "selectedProduct". For example onchange="selectRate(this)"......but I think this is a different question IMHO. I have the impression I am now developing instead of you and at the end you probably wont even appreciate my help by accepting the original answer...so: good luck and  bye

Comment: I am not so good with javascript and I would like to accomplish this with java only. I hope it is possible!!!

Comment: I surely do appreciate your help. I would accept your answer when the thing I want to do is ....... done!

Comment: I wonder why no one else is answering my question. Is the thing I want to do really so difficult to do?

Comment: Why Java only of you are already using javascript. No it's no hard to do it in java only but required to write so much I dont even want to start. Just create a javascript function selectRate() and set the rate that was selected by the user.

Comment: I dont need your points! Just wanna help you and get it over with...see my edit reply.